# Dealing with collegue who tries to steal projects

Tags: work-environment, colleagues, unprofessional-behavior

I am working in a team that supports operation. The team is awesome but when I get a project a guy wants it and start digging nose into it until he makes it his through contacts with vendor and stakeholders as he was working with them earlier than me. He takes one project and then another but does not get full knowledge of it. I think he is taking them in order to impress manager and show his work. Is there any way to handle this and get involved in work without his nose in it?

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: Are your projects assigned by your manager?  If so, why are you not telling your manager that this person is interfering?

Comment: Thanks. @Jane S they are more operational task rather than project I must say. One handling one system and other handling another. I being new is not exposed to any information although manager has provided the authority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, who assigns your projects to you? Your manager? In that case, talk to your colleague first and state that you find his current behaviour problematic and that it makes you uncomfortable. Try not to come off as hostile and try to have a productive dialogue. If this fails, try to talk to your manager about it.

Your manager will then have to put his foot down eventually. Failing that, you can try and escalate to HR or higher management, but beware, your manager might resent you for that.

Answer (score 3):

Some good answers already, but I want to add an additional viewpoint and resolution.

There may be another reason that he/she is getting involved. Someone may be tasking your colleague to oversee what you are doing as they are more experienced. To the bosses it doesn't matter so much who does the job as that it is being done well. I have been put in this position many times to keep an eye on less experienced colleagues. Eventually if they don't shape up and prove themselves they've been let go.

Or this may be the impression your colleague is making about you to management, that your competence is questionable. Either way you need to combat it.

A good strategy would be to be very organised about how you approach projects, keep good clean pertinent records and do everything by the book. Make sure there are no flaws that someone could pounce on. In other words work like a professional. Eventually you'll earn your laurels.

Complaining about it would be my last resort only if I thought the colleague was maliciously elbowing me aside. If I went down that track I wouldn't bother speaking to them. I would ask management politely why I'm being taken off such and such a project after putting so much effort into it, ask them if there is some area I need to improve on and basically put the onus on them to explain why it is happening while pointing out how much you would value a chance to prove yourself by completing a project. Then move forwards dependent on their answer. It's always preferable to make the manager question his/her own reasoning and motivations rather than to be confrontational about things, if possible.

Comment: good note to be remembered!

Answer (score 2):

There is pretty much only one thing you can do.

Ask him not to interfere with your projects, as it is making you very uncomfortable.

If he continues to do it, you have to escalate it to your management, as it is affecting your productivity and maybe his' too, as he is multi-tasking.